# Can't add new locale in the new iTunes Connect

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

In the new iTunes connect I can't add new languages in my new version of my app like the previous version of iTunes Connect in the "Version Information" page.
How to add new languages?

See the screenshot
[image]

Thanks.

EDIT:

OK If you scroll down you can discover new languages.
I don't see any scrollbar if you don't scroll by the way.

Comment: I feel really stupid now because I didn't see it either. Thanks for this.

Comment: That's one small UI design flaw that had me scratching my head for 3 days haha. Thank you.